# RegEx Vin Validation for pre 1980 and post 1980

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In 1981, Vehicle Identification Numbers (VINs) were standardized using a seventeen digit system. Prior to 1981, manufacturers used VINs unique to their own company and there was no accepted standard for these numbers, so different manufacturers used different formats..
http://www.crankshaftcoalition.com/wiki/VIN_decoding

It required all over-the-road-vehicles sold to contain a 17-character VIN, which does not include the letters I (i), O (o), or Q (q) (to avoid confusion with numerals 1 and 0).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number

So what I am trying to accomplish is having a drop down and if anywhere from 1980 - 1900 is chosen the VIN will either follow the guidelines of the manufactures or just not apply at all where the letters I (i), O (o), or Q (q) could be used and any number of characters/numbers. But then if 1981 and later is chosen the RegEx to kick in and demand it to be formatted with the Expression that I have showing a valid or invalid VIN.

Plugged a valid VIN in for the time being for testing purposes.. if you delete the last number it will show "Invalid Vin"

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/ommLz4th/1/

RegExp

```
^[A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{8}[\\dX][A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{2}\\d{6}$
```

jQuery Vin Validator

```
    $(function() {
  $("#vin").on("keyup blur", function() {
    if (validateVin($("#vin").val())) {
      $("#result").css('color', 'green').html("Valid VIN");
      $("#vin").removeClass("not-ok").addClass("ok");
    } else {
      $("#result").css('color', 'red').html("Invalid VIN");
      $("#vin").removeClass("ok").addClass("not-ok");
    }
  });
});


function validateVin(vin) {
  var re = new RegExp("^[A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{8}[\\dX][A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{2}\\d{6}$");
  return vin.match(re);
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label name="vin">VIN</label>
<input type="text" id="vin" value="1FAFP40634F172825" />
<span id="result"></span>
```

Drop Down for test purposes

```
<select name="vehicleyear" id="vehicleyear">
    <option value="">Choose Year</option>
    <option value="1985">1985</option>
    <option value="1984">1984</option>
    <option value="1983">1983</option>
    <option value="1982">1982</option>
    <option value="1981">1981</option>
    <option value="1980">1980</option>
    <option value="1979">1979</option>
    <option value="1978">1978</option>
    <option value="1977">1977</option>
    <option value="1976">1976</option>
    <option value="1975">1975</option>
    <option value="1974">1974</option>
</select>
```

Actual Drop down

```
<cfparam name="form.vehicleyear" default="">

<cfset VARIABLES.y1=DatePart("yyyy",Now())>
<cfset VARIABLES.y2=VARIABLES.y1+2>

<cfif Val(form.vehicleyear) LT VARIABLES.y1 or Val(form.vehicleyear) GT VARIABLES.y2>
</cfif>

 <cfoutput>
    <cfselect name="vehicleyear" id="vehicleyear" required="yes" message="Please select vehicle year.">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Year</option>
    <cfloop index="i" from="#VARIABLES.y2#" to="1900" step="-1">
    <option value="#i#"<cfif form.vehicleyear EQ i> selected</cfif>>#NumberFormat(i,"0000")#</option>
    </cfloop>
    </cfselect>
 </cfoutput>
```

Comment: You're going to have a heck of a time validating the check digit on 1981- VINs via regex. I strongly recommend [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number) as a reference on this topic.

Comment: Do you really mean "1980 - 1900"?

Comment: Basically 1980 - (the first car ever made) hahaha... I just can not miss a year, Yes I know the Model T made its debut in 1908 :)

Comment: Even though many suggest Karl Benz from Germany created the first true automobile in 1885/1886.

Comment: I am surprised this is not a topic people are swarming to learn ;) hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ain't gonna develop the RegExps for you but the overall pattern should be something like this :

```
$(function() {
    $("#vin").on("keyup blur", function() {
        if ( validateVin( this.value, Number($("#vehicleyear").val()) ) ) {
            $("#result").css('color', 'green').html("Valid VIN");
            $("#vin").removeClass("not-ok").addClass("ok");
        } else {
            $("#result").css('color', 'red').html("Invalid VIN");
            $("#vin").removeClass("ok").addClass("not-ok");
        }
    });
    function validateVin(vin, date) {
        if(date > 1980) {
            var re = new RegExp("^[A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{8}[\\dX][A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{2}\\d{6}$");
            return vin.match(re);
        } else {
            //Pre validation are rules to complex. We are forced to assume the vin is valid.
            //Though really at least a simple test would be preferable - eg vin.length >= 20 or whatever
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Note that `vin` *and `date`* are passed to `validateVin()` thus allowing the code to branch.

Comment: I haven't tried to penetrate the validation rules but yes probably what you say; your RegExp (if correct) will apply to one of the branches and some other RegExp (or whatever) will apply to the other.

Comment: Well yes, but then you're not validating post-1980 vins. Surely you want to validate both pre- and post-?

Comment: What about "no Is or Os" rule, does it not apply to pre- and post-1980?

Comment: OK, so your RegExp applies to post-1980 and you are forced to assume all pre-1980 vins to be OK?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63805/discussion-between-vicki-and-roamer-1888).

Comment: Best regex I've found is `^[^\\Wioq]{17}$`